# How to link ndk module using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I have an Android Studio project to which I've added an ndk module.  My ndk module builds and creates lots of different .so files in various build/intermediates directories.  However, when I run the app it is unable to load the library .so from my System.loadLibrary call.

Java files that I include in the same module are found just fine so I was expecting Android Studio to 'find' the ndk files as well.

In looking at the [google hello-libs demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs) I see that they have added a step in the CMakeLists.txt file to set the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY:

`set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../distribution)
set_target_properties(gperf
                      PROPERTIES
                      LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                      "${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}")`

and then added an associated reference in app:build.gradle

`jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../distribution/gperf/lib']`

Adding similar entries to my project allowed it to run properly.

Is there a simpler way to cause an ndk compiled module to be included in the main application?   If not, is there a way to do it without having to figure out all the relative ../../ path elements.  I guess I was hoping the module CMakeLists.txt would be
the same configuration regardless of what other projects it might be included in but having to know where it's including project is located seems to break this.

Comment: Check out my repo: https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line. I might have a workaround for you.

Comment: An interesting approach but I prefer to stay within the confines of Android Studio for now.